# How to draw a face to SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm coding for my kids. I'm using sprite-kit to create a simple game for them. At the moment I'm struggling with how to draw a face to an arbitrary skshapenode? I know that there is no holes within the shape but other than that it can be of any shape. Dispite what shape it is, I would like to draw eyes and mouth to it programmatically. The shapes can came in many sizes.

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: What kind of face are you looking to draw? A real-looking, cartoon-like, smiley, or other?

Comment: No just a cute face. Think cloud with eyes and mouth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to draw a smiley face with an `SKShapeNode`. It provides a framework that you can expand upon to draw more complex faces.

We start by extending the `UIBezierPath` class to add instance methods that are useful for drawing faces. The first method adds a circle to a path at a given location and with a specified radius. The `moveToPoint` statement moves the current point of a path to a new location. This is the equivalent of picking up a "pen" and moving it to a new location to draw a different, non-connected object. The second method draws a half circle with the open side facing up. This can be used to draw a smile. Note that extensions cannot be defined within a class. You can place it above your `GameScene` definition.

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func addCircle(center:CGPoint, radius:CGFloat) {
        self.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(center.x+radius, center.y))
        self.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    }
    func addHalfCircle(center:CGPoint, radius:CGFloat) {
        self.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(center.x+radius, center.y))
        self.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: false)
    }
}
```

We can now use the extended `UIBezierPath` class to draw a face consisting of a face outline (a large circle), eyes (two small circles), and a mouth (a half circle). The face is constructed by adding components of the face to a path and then attaching the path to an `SKShapeNode`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        let face = SKShapeNode()
        // The argument determines the size of the face
        face.path = drawFace(50)
        face.lineWidth = 2
        // Place the face in the center of the scene
        face.position = CGPointMake (CGRectGetMidX(view.frame),CGRectGetMidY(view.frame))
        addChild(face)
    }

    func drawFace(radius:CGFloat) -> CGPathRef {

        var path = UIBezierPath()

        // Add the outline of the face
        let center = CGPointZero
        path.addCircle(center, radius: radius)

        // Add the eyes
        let eyeOffset = radius * 0.35
        let eyeRadius = radius * 0.125

        let left = CGPointMake(-eyeOffset, eyeOffset)
        path.addCircle(left, radius: eyeRadius)

        let right = CGPointMake(eyeOffset, eyeOffset)
        path.addCircle(right, radius: eyeRadius)

        // Add the mouth
        let smileRadius = radius*0.65
        path.addHalfCircle(center, radius: smileRadius)

        return path.CGPath
    }        
}
```